# Create function that iterates across dataframe columns

Tags: r, dataframe, function, sorting, apply

I have a `wide format` `dataframe` which is arranged based on the minimum value for each `column` (high to low). The largest minimum value is `column 1` and the smallest minimum value is the `last column` What I want to achieve is that the minimum value of each `column` coincides with the position of the corresponding value in the next `column` and so on.

Here is an example `dataframe`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

MA_vol <- c(0.2486667, 0.2463333, 0.2426667, 0.2423333, 0.2376667, 0.2323333, 0.2270000, 0.2246667, 0.2216667, 0.2203333, 0.2183333, 0.2126667, 0.2076667, 0.2060000)
R_id <- rep(15, length(MA_vol))
df1 <- data.frame(R_id, MA_vol)

MA_vol <- c(0.2073333, 0.2053333, 0.2013333, 0.1993333, 0.1973333, 0.1970000, 0.1966667, 0.1946667, 0.1920000, 0.1890000, 0.1883333, 0.1866667, 0.1843333, 0.1823333, 0.1810000)
R_id <- rep(13, length(MA_vol))
df2 <- data.frame(R_id, MA_vol)

MA_vol <- c(0.2016667, 0.1996667, 0.1980000, 0.1970000, 0.1963333, 0.1956667, 0.1930000, 0.1913333, 0.1900000, 0.1893333, 0.1890000, 0.1863333, 0.1853333, 0.1820000, 0.1800000, 0.1780000, 0.1763333)
R_id <- rep(4, length(MA_vol))
df3 <- data.frame(R_id, MA_vol)

MA_vol <- c(0.2180000, 0.2146667, 0.2126667, 0.2103333, 0.2070000, 0.2040000, 0.2010000, 0.1993333, 0.1956667, 0.1950000, 0.1926667, 0.1920000, 0.1896667, 0.1890000, 0.1856667, 0.1830000, 0.1786667, 0.1763333, 0.1733333, 0.1720000, 0.1700000, 0.1686667, 0.1670000)
R_id <- rep(8, length(MA_vol))
df4 <- data.frame(R_id, MA_vol)

MA_vol <- c(0.2096667, 0.2063333, 0.2030000, 0.1993333, 0.1953333, 0.1916667, 0.1880000, 0.1870000, 0.1850000, 0.1830000, 0.1783333, 0.1753333, 0.1726667, 0.1716667, 0.1673333, 0.1666667, 0.1656667) 
R_id <- rep(2, length(MA_vol))
df5 <- data.frame(R_id, MA_vol)

df <- bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)

# Order based on each min value (high to low)
R_minvalues <- df %>%
  group_by(R_id) %>%                # group by recession id
  slice(which.min(MA_vol)) %>%      # extract min volume values for each recession
  select(R_id, MA_vol)

x <- R_minvalues[with(R_minvalues, order(-MA_vol)), ]     # order by MA-vol min value (high to low)
R_id_order <- as.numeric(x$R_id)

# Reorder dataframe based on R_minvalues (high to low)
MRC_DF <- df %>%
  arrange(match(R_id, R_id_order)) %>%       # match R_id rows with R_id_order
  transform(t = 1:nrow(df)) %>%     # create t (time) column the length of the df
  select(t, R_id, MA_vol)                    # select columns

R_order_chr <- as.character(R_id_order)     # convert R_id_order to character so can rearrange columns

MRC_DF_wide <- dcast(setDT(MRC_DF), t ~ R_id, value.var = "MA_vol") %>%     # convert df to wide format 
  select(all_of(R_order_chr))       # rearrange column order

colnames(MRC_DF_wide)[1:ncol(MRC_DF_wide)] <-
  paste("R", colnames(MRC_DF_wide)[1:ncol(MRC_DF_wide)], sep = "")     # add "R_" to start of numbers so syntax is correct
```

The following code produces the desired outcome, but it only does one column at a time and requires manual input (specify column name):

```
# identify positional index of minimum value and corresponding closest value in next column 
a <- which.min(MRC_DF_wide$R15)     # position of min value in 1st column 
b <-
  which.min(abs(MRC_DF_wide$R13 - min(MRC_DF_wide$R15, na.rm = TRUE)))     # position of closest value in 2nd column 
                # 2nd column           # 1st column

c <- b - a     # positional index difference 

# shift column rows up 
shift <- function(x, n){
  c(x[-(seq(n))], rep(NA, n))
}

MRC_DF_wide$R13 <- shift(MRC_DF_wide$R13, c)     # shift 2nd column up by positional index difference
```

I would like to create a function that iterates over columns 1 & 2, then 2 & 3 and so on for `ncol` of the `dataframe`. This is my attempt which highlights the column id but it is unsuccessful:

```
matching.strip.fn <- function(df) {
  min_index <- which.min(df[[i]])     # positional index of min value in 1st column
  match_index <- which.min(abs(df[[i+1]] - min(df[[i]], na.rm = TRUE)))     # positional index of closest value in 2nd column
                            # 2nd column       1st column 
  index_diff <- match_index - min_index     # positional index difference 
  
  df$i + 1 <- c(df[-(seq(index_diff))], rep(NA, index_diff))     # shift values up by positional difference in 2nd column 
# 2nd column
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you'll get the best response if you can write a function that accepts the two input columns as input arguments and returns your desired dataframe result.  Include this function in your question.  With this, the community can focus on the essential nature of your question without getting caught up in the other details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this with `purrr::accumulate()` quite handily:

```r
accumulate(MRC_DF_wide, \(.x, .y) {
  .y <- .y[!is.na(.y)]
  pos <- which.min(.x) - which.min(abs(min(.x, na.rm = T) - .y))
  c(rep(NA, pos), .y, rep(NA, length(.x) - pos - length(.y)))
})  |>
  set_names(names(MRC_DF_wide)) |>
  as.data.frame() %>%
  filter(apply(., 1, \(x) ! all(is.na(x))))
#>          R15       R13        R4        R8        R2
#> 1  0.2486667        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 2  0.2463333        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 3  0.2426667        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 4  0.2423333        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 5  0.2376667        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 6  0.2323333        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 7  0.2270000        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 8  0.2246667        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 9  0.2216667        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 10 0.2203333        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 11 0.2183333        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 12 0.2126667        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 13 0.2076667 0.2073333        NA 0.2180000        NA
#> 14 0.2060000 0.2053333 0.2016667 0.2146667        NA
#> 15        NA 0.2013333 0.1996667 0.2126667        NA
#> 16        NA 0.1993333 0.1980000 0.2103333        NA
#> 17        NA 0.1973333 0.1970000 0.2070000        NA
#> 18        NA 0.1970000 0.1963333 0.2040000        NA
#> 19        NA 0.1966667 0.1956667 0.2010000        NA
#> 20        NA 0.1946667 0.1930000 0.1993333        NA
#> 21        NA 0.1920000 0.1913333 0.1956667 0.2096667
#> 22        NA 0.1890000 0.1900000 0.1950000 0.2063333
#> 23        NA 0.1883333 0.1893333 0.1926667 0.2030000
#> 24        NA 0.1866667 0.1890000 0.1920000 0.1993333
#> 25        NA 0.1843333 0.1863333 0.1896667 0.1953333
#> 26        NA 0.1823333 0.1853333 0.1890000 0.1916667
#> 27        NA 0.1810000 0.1820000 0.1856667 0.1880000
#> 28        NA        NA 0.1800000 0.1830000 0.1870000
#> 29        NA        NA 0.1780000 0.1786667 0.1850000
#> 30        NA        NA 0.1763333 0.1763333 0.1830000
#> 31        NA        NA        NA 0.1733333 0.1783333
#> 32        NA        NA        NA 0.1720000 0.1753333
#> 33        NA        NA        NA 0.1700000 0.1726667
#> 34        NA        NA        NA 0.1686667 0.1716667
#> 35        NA        NA        NA 0.1670000 0.1673333
#> 36        NA        NA        NA        NA 0.1666667
#> 37        NA        NA        NA        NA 0.1656667
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi @shs, thanks for your response. How would I adapt the code so the minimum value matches with the closest value in the next column? For example, column R8 min.value = 0.167 so values in column R2 should be shifted down so the value 0.1673 is on the same row. If you could provide a bit more detail on the accumulation step, that would help my understanding thanks.

Comment: I edited the code to conform to your clarification of the alignment rule. A simple illustration of how accumulate works can be found on the [bottom right of the second page of the purrr cheat sheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/main/purrr.pdf). For a more extensive explanation you may want to read [the corresponding subchapter of Hadley Wickham's Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#accumulate)

Comment: That is probably because of the R Version (not RStudio). R 4.1 introduced the native pipe `|>` and shorthand functions `\(...) ...`

Comment: Thanks for your help, like you said the unexpected error tokens were because of the R version not RStudio